# Predicting housing pricing with less than 1000 samples

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, lasso, boosting

Dataset link is here at [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/arianghasemi/tehran-large-houses) with 724 samples .
We know that **area** and **price** columns [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) is symmetrical by Kaggle analysis.
First I tried this regression models to check their accuracy with cross validation by fiting on the dataset:

```
lasso = make_pipeline(RobustScaler(), Lasso(alpha =0.0005, random_state=1,tol = 0.1))

ENet = make_pipeline(RobustScaler(), ElasticNet(alpha=0.0005, l1_ratio=.9, random_state=3,tol=1.5))

GBoost = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=3000, learning_rate=0.05,
                               max_depth=4, max_features='sqrt',
                               min_samples_leaf=15, min_samples_split=10, 
                               loss='huber', random_state =5)

KRR = KernelRidge(alpha=0.005, kernel='polynomial', degree=2, coef0=2.5)
```

But the score that I got in average wasnt above **40%** .

**Second Attempt:**
I tried to remove **warehouse** columns because all values was 1 and correlation of **warehouse** column with **price** was near 0 . Again , I've got 40% accuracy by average(on all models that applied).

**Third Attempt**:
I tried to remove **parking** and **elevator** columns too , because nearly 90% of their data was equal to 1.
Again , I've got 40% accuracy by average.

**Question:**
I think I should improve my models by selecting correct parameters but I don't know what is best parameters that I must use based on **this dataset** . Any ideas?

Comment: This might be helpful https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#grid-search (`GridSearchCV` in particular)

Comment: What does "accuracy" mean when you're predicting *prices*?

Comment: @Sycorax cross_val_score() function default method.